# Is there a better way to do this? i.e. Chain the named scopes more nicely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope, method-chaining

This code works fine bu I'm looking at it and thinking it could be cleaner. Perhaps there is a more idiomatic ruby / rails way of doing this? The order is important because the member_of scope has to come last but before the pagination (which returns a collection and not a scope)

The one advantage of this is that it's pretty clear what's happening

```
@locations = Location.send(params[:type]) if type_sent_and_valid? #refine to a particular type if present
@locations = (@locations || Location.locatable).near(latlng_params) if latlng_sent? #refine to location

@locations = (@locations || Location).member_of(@interest_group.id).paginate(:page=>params[:page], :per_page=>20)
```

This if a params string was something like this:

```
?lat=50&lng=150&type=restaurant&page=1
```

Then it should yield this

```
Location.restaurant.near([50.0,150.0]).member_of(@interest_group).paginate(:page=>1, :per_page=>20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to clean this up is to use a sliding scope mechanism where you move the scope one step at a time using the same variable:

```
location_scope = Location

if (type_sent_and_valid?)
  location_scope = location_scope.send(params[:type])
end

if (latlng_sent?)
  location_scope = location_scope.locatable.near(latlng_params)
end

location_scope = location_scope.member_of(@interest_group.id)

@locations = location_scope.paginate(:page=>params[:page], :per_page=>20)
```

You can add other conditions as required.